# Where does Internet Explorer (IE9) store the URLs of the tabs in the current session

Tags: internet-explorer-9, session-restore

Let's say that you open an Internet Explorer (IE9) window and open a few tabs to various URLs.

Then while this is open IE crashes for some reason (or if you use Taskmgr.exe to kill the IE process).

The next time you open IE (most of the time), it will ask if you want to restore the previous session. If you choose to restore the previous session, IE will re-open all the tabs and windows of the previous session.

Similarly, if you click "Tools" -> "Restore last browsing session".

Where does IE store the URLs of the open windows and tabs in the current (one or many) open IE sessions?

I'm interested in this for IE9, but I'll probably change to IE10 or IE11 soon, so I'd also be interested in an answer for this for IE10/11 if it is different.

Answer (score 1):

They do not appear to be stored as URLs.  There are multiple binary data stores in your local appdata folder (`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery`).  There are separate stores for the different experiences and integrity levels.

There do not appear to be any user editable files.

Not sure if this helps, but I hope it does (somehow)...

-- Lance